# How to preprocess CUPS' `lp` with a script for a specific printer?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, printing, cups, lp

(How) Is it possible to preprocess `lp` automatically with a script? Piping inbetween (`fileToPrint | script.sh | lp -d myPrinter`) is no option for me, because I have a lot of source code that does `lp` directly (`lp -d myPrinter filetoPrint`) and there is currently no intention to change this, especially since the script is only needed for one specific printer.

I'm thinking of something like `lpoption` where I could say (pseduocode) `preprocess myPrinter with script.sh` (and only for myPrinter, not for myOtherPrinter).

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled over `tea4cups` (in Debian the Package is `cups-tea4cups`), where one can do exactly what I want, like this:

```
# tea4cups.conf
[myprinter] # just the cups printer name
filter: mycommand
# pipes everything though mycommand, like "<input> | mycommand | lp"
# if the printer URI is prefixed with 'tea4cups://'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [write your own backend](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_Your_Own_Backends_to_Print_with_CUPS) that runs the preprocessing and then hands it off to whatever actual backend you're normally using.  When you set up the printer, you'd using your custom backend in the URI.

I actually have done something similar to allow CUPS to print to a locally-patched LPRng server.

Comment: +1, thanks for interesting the link, I learned something new with it. But I found a solution that works better (easier) for me, so I wrote my answer.